# Relation between compact open subgroups and lattices

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field, $\mathfrak o$ its ring of units and $\mathfrak p$ its unique maximal ideal. I would like to show that $K=GL_2(\mathfrak o)$ is the unique maximal compact open subgroup of $GL_2(F)$ up to conjugacy.

The hints I am given suggest to relate this to *lattices*, and I don't see much the relation. The hints are as follow:

- show that there exists a $K$-stable $\mathfrak o$-lattice (here we can take whatever $\mathfrak o$-lattice $\Lambda$ and then $K\Lambda$ is $\mathfrak o$-stable)
- show that the only $GL_2(\mathfrak o)$-stable lattices are $\mathfrak p^j \oplus \mathfrak p^j$ (I guess this is merely a matter of operating on line/columns and looking at valuations)

However, what next? I don't see how to relate the properties of these lattices to a relation between $K$ and $GL_2(\mathfrak o)$. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-archimedean number field"? Usually, a "number field" means that it is a finite extension of ${\mathbb Q}$. Do you mean a number field equipped with a NA valuation?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I meant non-archimedean field, thank you. I corrected in the original post!

Comment: This is still unclear, do you mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Archimedean_ordered_field ?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Non-archimedean local field then, finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ typically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field. I added this precision to the post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have two lattices $L, L'$, try to find $g \in GL_2(F)$ such that $g(L)=L'$.

Now if $K, K'$ are the stabiliser subgroups corresponding to the respective lattices, how are they related, using the above $g$?